# Exercises where multivariable calculus and differential equations are mixed

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, reference-request

I have a course where multivariable calculus and differential equations are mixed, as an application of what you did in class, Hadamard's theorem:

> Let $f\in \mathcal{C}^2(\Bbb{R}^n,\Bbb{R}^n)$
>
> If $f(0)=0$ and that for all $x\in \Bbb{R}^n$ the derivative is invertible and satisfies $$\Vert (df_x)^{-1}\Vert\le A\Vert x\Vert+B$$ where $A,B$ are two fixed constant. Then $f$ is a diffeomorphism.

It was very interesting, we use Cauchy-Lipschitz's Theorem, explosion in finite time and local inversion theorem.

*Unfortunately*, I didn't find a suitable reference in my library for these kind of exercises.

I am not sure where I am suppose to search, I am looking for exercises, any ideas?

Comment: [This book](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781461200598) might be interesting for you.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thanks, I will take a look at it.